# PyTorch: Why does validation accuracy change once calling it inside or outside training epochs loop?

Tags: python, validation, testing, deep-learning, pytorch

I am learning deep learning and I am trying to use the RNN with train, test and validation sets on time series finance data. Below is my code :

```
def get_lr(optimizer):
    for param_group in optimizer.param_groups:
        return param_group['lr']


# In[63]:


def train_model(epoch, model, optimizer, train_loader):
    model.train()
    t0 = time.time()
    correct = 0
    total = 0
    final_loss = 0
    for batch_idx, (X,labels) in enumerate(train_loader):
        data,labels = map(lambda x: Variable(x), [X,labels])
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        output = model(data)
        device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
        ##print('device : ', device)
        final_output=output.to(device)
        loss = F.cross_entropy(final_output, labels)
        final_loss += loss.item()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        print('predicted labels',final_output.squeeze())
        #print('Actual labels',labels.squeeze())
        print('Train Epoch: {} Batch: {} [{}/{} ({:.2f}%, time:{:.2f}s)]\tBatch Loss: {:.6f}'.format(
                epoch, batch_idx, batch_idx * len(data), len(train_loader.dataset),
                100. * batch_idx / len(train_loader), time.time() - t0,
                final_loss))
                ##avg_loss))
        _, predicted = torch.max(output.data, 1)
        total += labels.size(0)
        correct += (predicted == labels).sum().item()
        t0 = time.time()
    final_loss /= (batch_idx+1)
    accuracy =  100*correct/total
    lr = get_lr(optimizer)
    learning_rates.append(lr)
    print('Training Accuracy : ',accuracy)
    print('Training Loss : ',final_loss)
    print('Learning Rate : ',lr)
    if epoch%epoch_interval == 0 or epoch ==1 or epoch == epochs: 
        path = base_path + 'models/RNN/rnn_'
        torch.save(model,path+str(epoch)+'.pth')
        ##torch.save(model,path)
        print('model saved')
    if epoch%plot_epoch_interval == 0 or epoch ==1 or epoch == epochs: 
        epochs_list.append(epoch)
        train_loss.append(final_loss)
        train_accuracies.append(accuracy)
    return lr,final_loss,accuracy


# In[166]:


def validate(epoch,model, val_loader,optimizer):
    model.eval()
    val_loss = 0
    correct = 0
    total = 0
    loss = 0
    ypred,ytrue,scores = [],[],[]
    for batch_idx,(X,labels) in enumerate(val_loader):
        data,labels = map(lambda x: Variable(x), [X,labels])
        output = model(data)
        device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
        final_val_output=output.to(device)
        val_loss += F.cross_entropy(final_val_output, labels)  # sum up batch loss
        _, predicted = torch.max(output.data, 1)
        total += labels.size(0)
        correct += (predicted == labels).sum().item()
        ypred.extend(predicted.tolist())
        ytrue.extend(labels.tolist())
        scores.extend(output.tolist())
    val_loss /= (batch_idx+1)
    accuracy =  100*correct/total
    if epoch%plot_epoch_interval == 0 or epoch ==1 or epoch == epochs: 
        validation_loss.append(val_loss.item())
        val_accuracies.append(accuracy)

    print('Accuracy : ',accuracy)
    print('\nVal set: Average loss: {:.4f}, Accuracy: {}/{} ({:.4f}%)\n'.format(
        val_loss, correct,total,accuracy))
    print("==============================================")
    return "{:.4f}%".format(100.* correct / total), accuracy,loss,ypred,ytrue,scores


# In[276]:

def test(data_loader,model):
    torch.manual_seed(1)
    np.random.seed(1)
    #data_loader = DataLoader(FinancialData(xtest,ytest), batch_size = batch_size, shuffle = False)
    model = torch.load(path)
    model.eval()
    for params in model.parameters():
         print(params)
    val_loss = 0
    correct = 0
    total = 0
    loss = 0
    ypred,ytrue,scores = [],[],[]
    with torch.no_grad():
        for batch_idx,(X,labels) in enumerate(data_loader):
            data,labels = map(lambda x: Variable(x), [X,labels])
            output = model(data)
            _, predicted = torch.max(output.data, 1)
            total += labels.size(0)
            correct += (predicted == labels).sum().item()
            ypred.extend(predicted.tolist())
            ytrue.extend(labels.tolist())
            scores.extend(output.tolist())
            accuracy =  100*correct/total

    print('Test Accuracy : ',accuracy)


# In[288]:


def train_on_batch(lr,epochs,momentum,X_train,Y_train,X_val,Y_val,batch_size):
    cuda=False
    seed=1
    torch.manual_seed(seed)

    train_loader = DataLoader(FinancialData(X_train,Y_train),batch_size=batch_size,shuffle=True) 
    val_loader = DataLoader(FinancialData(X_val,Y_val),batch_size=batch_size,shuffle=False) 
    test_loader = DataLoader(FinancialData(X_test_new,Y_test), batch_size = batch_size, shuffle = False)
    input_size = 1
    hid_size = 10
    num_layers = 2
    num_classes = len(np.unique(Y_train))
    dropRate = 0.0
    bidirection = True
    model = Network(input_size=input_size,hid_size =hid_size,window_size = window_size,num_layers=num_layers,
                num_classes=num_classes,dropRate = dropRate,bidirection=bidirection)
    ypred,ytrue, scores = [],[],[]
    for params in model.parameters():
        print(params)
    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=lr, betas=(0.9, 0.999), eps=1e-08, weight_decay=1e-4, amsgrad=False)

    scheduler = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.ReduceLROnPlateau(optimizer,'max', factor=0.25, patience=6, verbose=True,
                                                            threshold_mode='abs', threshold=0.01, min_lr=1e-6)

    #scheduler = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.ReduceLROnPlateau(optimizer, 'max', factor=0.5, patience=5,
    #                                                       verbose=True,threshold_mode='abs', threshold=0.01, 
    #                                                       min_lr=1e-6)
    path = base_path + 'models/RNN/rnn_best_model.pth'
    best_val_loss = 0
    best_val_acc = 0
    best_epoch = 0
    best_lr = lr
    best_tr_acc = 0
    for epoch in range(1, epochs + 1):
        tuned_lr,tr_loss,tr_acc = train_model(epoch, model, optimizer, train_loader)
        acc_str, val_acc, val_loss, ypred, ytrue, scores = validate(epoch,model,val_loader,optimizer)
        if val_acc >= best_val_acc:
                torch.save(model,path)
                #best_val_loss = val_loss
                best_val_acc = val_acc
                best_epoch = epoch
                best_lr = tuned_lr
                best_tr_acc = tr_acc
        scheduler.step(val_acc)
        #scheduler.step(tr_acc)
        print('='*100)
#         for params in model.parameters():
#             print(params)
#         print('='*100)
    test(val_loader,model)
    test(test_loader,model)
    #validate(epoch,model,val_loader,optimizer)
    #validate(epoch,model,test_loader,optimizer)
    print('best epoch : {}, best_lr : {}, best_tr_acc : {}, best val_acc : {:.4f}\n'.format(best_epoch,best_lr,best_tr_acc,best_val_acc))    
    scores = np.asarray(scores)
    return tr_acc,val_acc, ypred, ytrue, scores


# In[289]:


cuda=torch.cuda.is_available()


X_train,Y_train,X_val,Y_val,X_test,Y_test = splitDataWithVal(feat_wise_data,labels_new,test_size=0.2,val_size=0.25)

X_train_new, X_val_new, X_test_new = standardizeDataVal(X_train, X_test, X_val, mode = 'Normalizer') 


# # Check for Class Imbalance

# In[292]:


Ytrain_df= pd.DataFrame(Y_train,columns=[0])
print(Ytrain_df.shape)
print(Ytrain_df.columns)
print(Ytrain_df.groupby(0).size())




train_loss = []
validation_loss = []
epochs_list = []
train_accuracies = []
val_accuracies = []
learning_rates = []
epoch_interval = 1#10
plot_epoch_interval = 5



lr = 0.01
momentum = 0.9
epochs = 3
batch_size = 4
print('batch_size : ',batch_size)
tr_acc,val_acc, ypred, ytrue, scores = train_on_batch(lr,epochs,momentum,X_train_new,Y_train,X_val_new,Y_val,batch_size)
```

I tested it for 3 epochs and saved models after every epoch. However, after 3rd epoch i.e. complete 3 epochs of training, when I test my model by calling test() function of my code, it gives 49.7% validation accuracy and 59.3% test accuracy.

Whereas if I use validate() function of my code, it gives 51.146% validation accuracy when called after 3rd epoch of training within training loop. Using validate() function after complete training of 3 epochs ie. outside for loop, I get 49.12% validation accuracy and 54.0697% test accuracy.

Why does validation accuracy change calling the same validate function twice i.e. once inside training epochs loop and other time after training epochs loop ? Also, which function is correct way of testing and validating, validate() or test()?

I even loaded all the models which I am saving after every epoch and checked their weights which are same as what they were seen during training. I am new to this domain.

Answer (score 1):

1. It is [not unusual](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Whenever_i_run_my_neural_network_I_get_different_result) to get different accuracies every time you run your code because the parameters are randomly initialised when the training starts. The algorithms AI algorithms are [stochastic](https://machinelearningmastery.com/randomness-in-machine-learning/) is nature i.e the models are [naturally dependent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891727/randomness-in-artificial-intelligence-machine-learning) on randomness.
2. Even I'm a new learner and had faced such doubts, even got confused between `Validation` and `Test` datasets. For testing the accuracy of the trained model use the `test()` function. [Use the `validation()`](https://machinelearningmastery.com/difference-test-validation-datasets/) function to give an unbiased estimate of the skill of the final tuned model when comparing or selecting between final models.

==========EDIT-1==========

3. So when you call the `validate()` function inside training loop it returns the accuracy calculated for **only** the **third** i.e the last epoch, and when you call the same `validate()` function after the training loop, the accuracy is calculated using the data it has *seen* through **all** the epochs. Try printing your *correct* variable so that you’ll notice the reason behind the accuracies! :)

Hope I'm clear in my explanation and do note that `validation` **does not learn** the dataset but [`only sees`](https://towardsdatascience.com/train-validation-and-test-sets-72cb40cba9e7) (i.e. fine-tune) it. Refer my point 2 and the links in point 2 for your second part of the question.

Comment: thanks for your response but like you said randomly initialised parameters are not there in my case since I  have set the seed. Due to this the model when loaded has the same weights as were during training. My question is not pertaining to randomness in accuracies due to this. It is that this behaviour is constant on running the code multiple time. the same 5 accuracies are obtained which are mentioned which should not be the case. My results are reproducible due to seed being set.

Comment: oh ok thanks for the clarification, will update my answer soon.

Comment: @POOJA GUPTA  I have updated my answer. Let me know if i’ve clarified your query.

Comment: I am printing the correct variable and it is seeing the same data in every epoch. Also, the model loaded is the one obtained at the end of the third epoch with same parameters which were there in thrid epoch after gradients calculated. According to em accuracies should not change when they are changing. Please look at the code and let me  know if you find any of the faults. Thanks for your time and response :). appreciate it !